# Is it possible to achieve binary compatibility in .NET library?

Tags: .net, vb6, interop, binary-compatibility

I have a .NET library visible in COM, and it's called from a vb6 application.

If I add some methods and release a new version (but don't erase or change signatures of existing methods), I would like being able to just install it in the production machine, and have it working. However, it seems that such approach doesn't work; I need to reompile the vb6 application.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What you're asking for is a lot easier than binary compatibility. You're late-binding with `IDispatch`.

Comment: Damn, you're right, late-binding. I guess the question is clear enough, anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can explicitly use the [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx) attribute on your COM interfaces and classes and the [`DispId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dispidattribute.aspx) attribute on your methods, fields and properties:

```
[Guid("0E213759-1679-4CD1-8322-566CF76928EF")]
public class SampleClass
{
    [DispId(8)]
    public void MyMethod() {}
}
```

Comment: Is this all I need? I have the Guid but not the DisId's. Will try this ASAP, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, Jammer, didn't see your comment until now. For future references, it worked like a charm.